Facing the error while running the code in selenium related to open a chrome browser
Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/failsafe/Policy
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.http/org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<clinit>(ClientConfig.java:33)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:83)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
    at First/test.Dashboard.main(Dashboard.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.failsafe.Policy
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 4 more

Trying to launch chrome browser throw selenium WebDriver, it has POM to test TestNG

Add the Failsafe Dependency in maven:
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.jodah</groupId>
    <artifactId>failsafe</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>


Ensure Selenium Dependencies Are Up to Date:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>

Update WebDriver and ChromeDriver And Ensure it matches your installed Chrome version.
Add WebDriver Binary to Path in the code or use WebDriverManager.
